# Spring Contracts: how to send a Collection of Strings as a RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, groovy, contract

A question about how to write a contract for a method annotated with @RequestBody taking a Collection of Strings as a parameter.
I have the following method:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/some/uri", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation("GET with body")
    public Response<Boolean> someMethod(@RequestParam(value = "key") final String key,
                                        @RequestBody final Collection<String> numbers){
        return some logic;
    }
```

and I have written the following contract for testing purposes:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract


Contract.make {
    description "Should return true"
    request {
        method POST()
        url("/some/uri?key=NEW_KEY")
        body'''["12345",
                "00143"]'''
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
        body '''true'''
    }
```

I keep getting 415, the test cannot find my method, I guess my mistake might be in the way I send the collection of strings, I have tried some other options but did not succed.

Comment: can you try to create a DTO with your key and collection of numbers as fields in it and pass it as parameter to your method with @RequestBody

Comment: The body is fine, try using a `List` instead of a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestions above but unfortunately they both did not solve my issue. The reason I got 415 was that when I added a body to my request, the check was also made behind the scenes on the content type of the body, so I had to explicitly specify that the body was in json format also in the request:

```
request {
        method POST()
        url("/some/uri?key=NEW_KEY")
        headers {header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
        body'''["12345",
                "00143"]'''
    }
```